# Angular dynamic select return promise when no option selected

Tags: angularjs

In my application, there is a from, in the form, there are two selects. The options of the second one depends on the first one. I use a `$http.get(url)` to fill the second options dynamically. All work except in this case :

The use is alowed to select nothing and submit the form. In this case, I expect the select should be a null or a blank string. But it is a promise object. How would this happens? Do you have any idea for changing the promise object to a empty list a blank string, if nothing selected?

For more information, I use the [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) for the select.

Here is a updated plunker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OoBTkL23dmj98vtOPOhr?p=preview).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: plunker example would be great :)

Comment: @K.Toress I have added the plunker example.

Comment: it should return a promise because u assign `$scope.formData.depart` to a `$http`, `$http` will return a promise object. what u need to achive :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes `$scope.formData.depart` is a promise object because u assign `$scope.formData.depart` to a `$http`, in angular `$http` returns a promise, see the [doc here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise with two $http specific methods: success and error.

so I think you need to print the form input values inside the `submit()`function,

see the [forked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/l08HgitbhDMIUzmOwEQl?p=preview), see the console.